# pg_repack binaries under windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, index-maintenance

We use postgres to manage our data in windows. Most of our installations run 9.x branch of postgres, although all versions of the database software is used (however pretty much all installations run under windows).

We would like to add `pg_repack` extensions to the installations. I tried to compile the package using msvc 2017 community edition. I adjusted the include and lib paths and eventually got to these linking errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol set_pglocale_pgservice   bin.2010    \pg_repack\msvc\pgut.obj    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol pgwin32_select   bin.2010     \pg_repack\msvc\pg_repack.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__dclass    bin.2010     \pg_repack\msvc\libpgport.lib(snprintf.obj)    1
```

Questions:

(1) what is missing to get this linked?

(2) are there pre-compiled pg_repack binaries for different versions of postgres in windows?

UPDATE:

Getting the code compiled in msvc 2017 community edition, one needs these adjustments:

(-1) take visual studio 2010 solution/project, not the `pg_repack.sln`

(0) install visual studio 2017 community edition. 2019 is harder, as they do not support 2010 projects anymore, one needs to upgrade those, and upgrading is buggy (creates additional work that needs fixes)

(1) set x64 target. 32 bit is a mess

(2) set include dirs:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\include\internal;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\include\server\port\win32;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\include\;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\include\server;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\include\server\port\server;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\include\server\port\win32_msvc;
```

(3) set library dirs:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib;
```

(4) remove `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` from C++/preprocessor

(5) change `libintl_8.lib` to `libintl.lib` in linking libraries

(6) add `postgres.lib` to adress undefined symbol `set_pg_locale_pgservice`. In visual studio console this gives exported symbols:

```
dumpbin -exports postgres.lib
```

(7) add `postgres.lib` to the linking libraries. Move this in front, so the _imp_sprintf undefined reference is also addressed

(8) imp_job_func underfined because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412951/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-fprintf-and-imp-iob-func-sdl2 recompile with visual studio 2010 platform toolset

(9) remove initialization errors

```
worker_conns workers   = {
    .num_workers     = 0,
    .conns           = NULL
};
```

(10) remove file from lib project:

```
lib\pgut\pgut-be.c
```

(11) compile the project and the library

(12) copy the dll to and exec to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib

```
copy /b/v/y "F:\git\pg_repack\msvc\bin\x64\8.3\bin\pg_repack.exe" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib"

copy /b/v/y "F:\git\pg_repack\msvc\bin\x64\8.3\lib\pg_repack.dll" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib"
copy /b/v/y "F:\git\pg_repack\msvc\bin\x64\8.3\lib\pg_repack.lib" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib"
```

(11) load dll

```
load 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib\pg_repack.dll'
```

(12) open `./lib/pg_repack.sql.in` in postgres in database of choice

(13) replace all `MODULE_PATHNAME` with `'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib\pg_repack.dll'`

```
CREATE FUNCTION repack.version() RETURNS text AS
'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_repack', 'repack_version'
LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

(14) Add pars to debugging

```
-h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -d play --table public.t
```

[image]

(15) get an debugging error

```
Exception thrown at 0x000000000059E908 in pg_repack.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x000000000059E908.
```

[image]

(16) add debuging infos

[image]

(17) die somewhere

[image]

Comment: This is one of the reasons why running Postgres on Linux in a production environment is typically a better choice: essentially all important tools are only available on Linux.

Comment: Note that except for 9.5 and 9.6 all versions of the "9.x branch" are [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) and 9.5 will be end-of-life in about 6 months

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I hear you. It is not good to have unsupported postgreses in productions (yet harder to update the systems in offline systems). Linux is a looot easier to administer and develop, of course! Unfortunately, not all decisions are based on what developers want :-( Sometimes business people have an upper hand.

Meanwhile I realized that two symbols (`set_pglocale_pgservice`   and `pgwin32_select`) can be found in `postgres.lib`, I wonder where `__imp__dclass` hides

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this?

Comment: not really.....